# Right click activated by holding left mouse button?

Tags: windows-xp, touchscreen, input-device

This feature is implemented in the tablet edition of Windows and under certain editions of Windows CE, but I'm looking to enable this functionality under a normal install of Windows XP.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some nice mouse button control software, the documentation is not that good but there are forums to ask questions, I think you need to learn how to set up layers using the advanced settings.

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

forums
http://forums.highrez.co.uk/viewforum.php?f=6

.